# How do I use $(this} in jquery with this example

Tags: javascript, logic, calculation

```js
var price = $('.fbits-valor').html().replace('R$ ', '').replace(',', '.'); //trocar , por .
var discount = '3%'
var cal; // váriaval que retornará o calculo

cal = (parseFloat(price) - (parseFloat(price) * (parseFloat((discount)) / 100))).toFixed(2);

var total = String(cal.replace('.', ',', '-', ''));

$('.precoTotalAssinante').html('R$ ' + total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spotPreco">
  <input type="hidden" tabindex="-1">

  <div class="precoDe">
    <span class="fbits-moeda">R$</span>
    <span class="fbits-valor">17,10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="precoPor com-precoDe">
    <span style="display:none;" class="porcentagem">
                                6%
                            </span>
    <span class="fbits-moeda">R$</span>
    <span class="fbits-valor">16,00</span>
    <span class="fbits-avista">à vista</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spotPreco">
  <input type="hidden" tabindex="-1">

  <div class="precoDe">
    <span class="fbits-moeda">R$</span>
    <span class="fbits-valor">30,10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="precoPor com-precoDe">
    <span style="display:none;" class="porcentagem">
                                6%
                            </span>
    <span class="fbits-moeda">R$</span>
    <span class="fbits-valor">16,00</span>
    <span class="fbits-avista">à vista</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my exercise, I need to calculate the value that is in my 'price' variable. However, I have several prices to calculate, and without the 'this', which I am not able to do, it is giving the result of one to everyone.

```js
var price = $('.fbits-valor').html().replace('R$ ', '').replace(',', '.'); //trocar , por .
    var discount = '3%'
    var cal; // váriaval que retornará o calculo
    
    cal = (parseFloat(price) - (parseFloat(price) * (parseFloat((discount)) / 100))).toFixed(2);
    
    var total = String(cal.replace('.', ',', '-', ''));
    
    $('.precoTotalAssinante').html('R$ ' + total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also post html code

Comment: @HimanshuPandey sorry, done!

Comment: Just go through basic of this in js http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/